# Laravel No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

Kinda new with this Laravel Framework business so bear with me a minute please.

I wanna know why am i getting the following error on my browser every time I run :

```
$ sudo php artisan serve
        Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Mon Jul 19 08:11:19 2021] PHP 7.4.15 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

is there someone out there that can help me fix it so that my existing php web app runs smoothly?

### **Web Browser Error:**

```
statusCode  500
title   "Oops Something went wrong!"
message "Oops Something went wrong!"
responseData    []
error   
type    "ErrorException"
message "require(/home/bitnami/api.tudo.com/storage/framework/views/../bootstrap/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /home/bitnami/api.tudo.com/resources/views/index.blade.php)"
code    0
file    "/home/bitnami/api.tudo.com/storage/framework/views/5759a88cbe727d45464c67b328a9f892cc0b9a9c.php"
line    14
```

---

```
**index.php located on the "/public" folder:**
      GNU nano 3.2                                                                  index.php                                                                             

    <?php
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Create The Application
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | First we need to get an application instance. This creates an instance
    | of the application / container and bootstraps the application so it
    | is ready to receive HTTP / Console requests from the environment.
    |
    */
    
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Run The Application
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
    | through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
    | the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
    | and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
    |
    */
    
    $app->run();
```

---

I know this is where the issue lies but cant figure out how to fix the "index.blade.php" in order order to run the php web app.

```
"**/resources/views**" folder
$ ls
backupfolder  index.blade.php  mails  uploads  vendor

index.blade.php

    <?php
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Create The Application
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | First we need to get an application instance. This creates an instance
    | of the application / container and bootstraps the application so it
    | is ready to receive HTTP / Console requests from the environment.
    |
    */
    
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Run The Application
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
    | through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
    | the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
    | and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
    |
    */
    
    $app->run();
```

---

```
**/routes/v1** folder

/routes/v1$ ls
admin.php  common  order  order.php  provider.php  service  transport  user.php  web.php

**web.php**

    <?php
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
    | It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
    | and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
    |
    */
    
    $router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
       return view('index');
    });
    
    $router->post('verify', 'LicenseController@verify');
    
    
    $router->post('base', 'V1\Common\CommonController@base');
    $router->get('cmspage/{type}', 'V1\Common\CommonController@cmspagetype');
    
    $router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function ($app) {
    
            $app->post('user/appsettings', 'V1\Common\CommonController@base');
    
            $app->post('provider/appsettings', 'V1\Common\CommonController@base');
    
            $app->get('countries', 'V1\Common\CommonController@countries_list');
    
            $app->get('states/{id}', 'V1\Common\CommonController@states_list');
    
            $app->get('cities/{id}', 'V1\Common\CommonController@cities_list');
    
            $app->post('/{provider}/social/login', 'V1\Common\SocialLoginController@handleSocialLogin');
    
            $app->post('/chat', 'V1\Common\CommonController@chat');
    
            $app->post('/provider/update/location', 'V1\Common\Provider\HomeController@update_location');
    
    });
    
    $router->get('/send/{type}/push', 'V1\Common\SocialLoginController@push');
    
    $router->get('v1/docs', ['as' => 'swagger-v1-lume.docs', 'middleware' => config('swagger-lume.routes.middleware.docs', []), 'uses' => 'V1\Common\SwaggerController@doc
    s']);
    
    $router->get('/api/v1/documentation', ['as' => 'swagger-v1-lume.api', 'middleware' => config('swagger-lume.routes.middleware.api', []), 'uses' => 'V1\Common\SwaggerCo
    ntroller@api']);
```

---

```
/bootstrap$ ls
app.php


        GNU nano 3.2                                                                   app.php                                                                              

    <?php
    
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
    
    try {
        (new Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__)))->load();
    } catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
        //
    }
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Create The Application
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
    | that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
    | application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
    |
    */
    
    $app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
        dirname(__DIR__)
    );
    
    $app->withFacades(true,
        [
            Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class => 'Socialite',
            Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\Facades\PushNotification::class => 'PushNotification',
            Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class => 'Notification',
            \App\Providers\WebPushServiceProvider::class => 'WebPush'
        ]);
    
    $app->withEloquent();
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Container Bindings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
    | register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
    | your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
    
    
    
    $app->singleton(
        Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
        App\Exceptions\Handler::class
    );
    
    $app->singleton(
        Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
        App\Console\Kernel::class
    );
    
    $app->singleton(
        Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory::class,
        function ($app) {
            return new Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager($app);
        }
    );
    
    $app->singleton(
        Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory::class,
        function ($app) {
            return new Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager($app);
        }
     );
    
    $app->configure('jwt');
    $app->configure('cors');
    $app->configure('auth');
    $app->configure('logging');
    $app->configure('settings');
    $app->configure('database');
    $app->configure('permission');
    $app->configure('filesystems');
    $app->configure('swagger-lume');
    $app->configure('webpush');
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
    | be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
    | route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
    |
    */
    
    $app->middleware([
    //     App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
               Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class
    ]);
    
    $app->routeMiddleware([
         'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
         'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
         'role'       => Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
         'demo'       => App\Http\Middleware\DemoModeMiddleware::class
    ]);
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
    | are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
    | totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
    |
    */
    
    // $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
    $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
    // $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
    
    $app->register(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
    $app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
    $app->register(Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class);
    $app->register(App\Providers\CustomMailServiceProvider::class);
    
    $app->register(Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class);
    
    $app->register(Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class);
    $app->register(Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class);
    $app->register(\SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider::class);
    //$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
    $app->alias('cache', \Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager::class);
    $app->configure('mail');
    $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
    $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
    $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);
    $app->alias('Excel', Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class);
    
    $app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Load The Application Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
    | the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
    | can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
    |
    */
    
    $app->router->group([
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ], function ($router) {
        require __DIR__.'/../routes/v1/web.php';
    });
    
    $app->router->group([
        'prefix' => 'api/v1/admin',
        'as' => 'admin.',
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ], function ($router) {
        require __DIR__.'/../routes/v1/admin.php';
    });
    
    $app->router->group([
            'prefix' => 'api/v1/shop',
        'as' => 'shop.',
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ], function ($router) {
        require __DIR__.'/../routes/v1/order.php';
    });
    
    $app->router->group([
        'prefix' => 'api/v1/user',
        'as' => 'user.',
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    
    ], function ($router) {
        require __DIR__.'/../routes/v1/user.php';
    });
    
    $app->router->group([
        'prefix' => 'api/v1/provider',
        'as' => 'provider.',
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ], function ($router) {
        require __DIR__.'/../routes/v1/provider.php';
    });
    
    
    return $app;
```

---

oh Man, I just hope someone out there is up to the challenge on assisting the complexity of this issue

```
[/bootstrap/app.php][1]
[Webrowser error][2]
[routes/v1$ sudo nano web.php ][3]
[resources/views/index.blade.php][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhuDc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1bWm.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TWqo.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRuTm.png
```

Comment: Well, xxx.blade.php is usually a front page, but seems you copy `$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'` from index.php into index.blade.php, so certainly it will throws an error because index.blade.php is not in the same directory as index.php, you can try to clear your index.blade.php

Comment: yeh like i said earlier on I knew that was the problem but how can I get it so that the right index is used so that the my existing web app is intepreted in the web browser?

Comment: There is no ``index.blade.php`` file under the ``resources/view/`` folder !! What let you delete that file?

Answer (score 0):

You may be having caching issues. There are many commands to clear the cache in Laravel.

To clear the cache in Laravel try:

- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @dragoon ah I see, where are you trying from web/localserver this time?